# incrementing an array of pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

this is probably an essentially trivial thing, but it somewhat escapes me, thus far..

`char * a3[2];

a3[0] = "abc";

a3[1] = "def";

char ** p;

p = a3;`

this works:

`printf("%p - \"%s\"\n", p, *(++p));`

this does not:

`printf("%p - \"%s\"\n", a3, *(++a3));`

the error i'm getting at compilation is:

> lvalue required as increment operand

what am i doing wrong, why and what is the solution for 'a3'?

Comment: The a3 variable is declared as an array of characters, I think you want to declare it as an array of pointers, so it should read char *a3[2] instead of char a3[2]

Comment: that was a mistake of copying over the code, you are right, yes, it was a pointer array, thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a3 is a constant pointer, you can not increment it. "p" however is a generic pointer to the start of a3 which can be incremented.

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign to `a3`, nor can you increment it. The array name is a constant, it can't be changed.

[c-faq](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/constptr.html)

Comment: @XXL The way you declared it, `a3` is not a pointer, period. You're probably missing a `*` in your question too (`char *a3[2]` ?)

Comment: it was missing an asterisk due to a failed paste, what i wanted to hear was that "the array name is constant, therefore it can not be modified" - which explains it well enough. you didn't have that part in your original reply, as it appeared only after you've edited your post - that is why i have asked a follow-up question of "why". anyhow, it has been addressed by now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
char *a3Ptr = a3;
printf("%p - \"%s\"\n", a3, *(++a3Ptr));
```

In C, a char array[] is different from char*, even if you can use a char* to reference the first location of an array of char.

> aren't both "p" and "a3" pointers to pointers?

Yes but a3 is constant. You can't modify it.

Answer (score 0):

`a3` is a name of an array. This about it as a constant pointer.

You cannot change it. You could use `a3 + 1` instead of `++a3`.

*Another problem* is with the use of "`%s`" for the `*(++a3)` argument. Since a3 is an array of char, `*a3` is a character and the appropriate format specifier should be `%c`.

Comment: a3 is an array of char * so that syntax should be ok...I misread it at first too...or maybe it was edited after you posted this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot increment or point any char array to something else after creating. You need to modify or access using index. `like a[1]`