# The V7 Echo program increments a constant pointer, how?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

 main(argc, argv)
 int argc;
 char *argv[];
 {
     register int i, nflg;

     nflg = 0;
     if(argc > 1 && argv[1][0] == '-' && argv[1][1] == 'n') {
      nflg++;
      argc--;
      argv++;     //Incements a constant pointer, how???
     }
     for(i=1; i<argc; i++) {
       fputs(argv[i], stdout);
       if (i < argc-1)
          putchar(' ');
     }
     if(nflg == 0)
       putchar('\n');
     exit(0);
 }
```

This program increments the value of argv, but argv is a constant pointer in C. Why don't I get a compilation error from this?

Comment: `argv` is not a pointer, it is an array of pointers. Arrays decay into pointers only when you pass them to functions expecting pointers.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226027/incrementing-an-array-of-pointers-in-c , here you are just looking at a a pre-standard C program.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: no, `argv` is *not* an array of pointers; remember that in the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[]` is interpreted as `T *a`.  In this case, `argv` is type `char **`, so the `++` is allowed.

Comment: @JohnBode: Please consider adding an answer, since I believe this answers the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the type of `argv` is `char **` (remember that in the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[]` is synonymous with `T *a`).  Thus it's a pointer type, not an array type, so use of the `++` operator is not immediately disallowed.

Secondly, while this looks like old-style K&R C, it's still considered valid.  Here's what the C99 standard ([n1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)) says about `argc` and `argv`:

> **5.1.2.2.1 Program startup**
> ...
> 2 If they are declared, the parameters to the `main` function shall obey the following
> constraints:
> ...
> — The parameters `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to by the `argv` array shall
> be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program
> startup and program termination.

So the expression `argv++` is perfectly legal.

Answer (score 4):

`argv` is not a const pointer. It's defined as `char *argv[]`. Since this is [K&R C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29#K.26R_C), that definition is in a different place than in ANSI C.

Secondly, even if it was defined as `const char *argv[]`, that is a *regular pointer to a constant string*. You can't write to memory through that pointer, but you can change the pointer itself.

A *constant pointer to a constant string* would be defined as `const char ** const argv`

Comment: So, In K&R C, is this valid:
   
     int a[3];
     a++;

Comment: This is valid in every C revision I know.  But the types of the function parameters are defined somewhere else.

Comment: That isn't valid ANSI C (I got `error: lvalue required as increment operand` from gcc), and I don't think it's valid K&R either. Incrementing a pointer (like `int *a; a++`) is valid. A pointer can be used as an array (`int *a; a[2];`), but an array defined with storage space isn't the same as a pointer.

Comment: @bhuwansahni `int a[3];a++` is wrong even in K&R C. `a` is an array and `argv` is a `char` pointer.
@Gandaro Are you sure that `int a[3]; a++` is valid? May be you were refering to `argv`??